# Route Resource BindingResolutionException

Tags: laravel, modular

I designed and implemented my project in a modular way, my main problem is this part,

I have no problem when I use this code

```
Route::get('/request/show-request',[RequestController::class,'show_request'])
 ->name('show_requests')->middleware('auth:api')
;
```

But when I use this piece of code, I get this error

```
Route::resource('student', StudentRequestController::class);
```

> > Target class [RequestManager/Http/Controllers\RequestManager\Http\Controllers\RequestController]
> > does not exist.
>
> at D:\my
> project\Fad-Modular\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:835
> 831▕
> 832▕         try {
> 833▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
> 834▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {   ➜ 835▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does
> not exist.", 0, $e);
> 836▕         }
> 837▕
> 838▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
> 839▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
>
> 1   [internal]:0
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
>
> 2   D:\my
> project\Fad-Modular\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:833
> ReflectionException::("Class "RequestManager/Http/Controllers\RequestManager\Http\Controllers\RequestController"
> does not exist")

**1-My Controller is resource controller and have all resource methods**

**2-The paths are completely correct and checked**

Do I have to do binding anything in my provider ?

Student Controller path :

> laravel/Modules/request_manager/Http/Controllers/StudentRequestController.php

and namespace of student controller :

> namespace RequestManager\Http\Controllers;

this is my module structure :

[image]

when i use the tinker and call method by tinker  :

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the `namespace` (in the file) that `StudentRequestController` has defined ? Also show the full path of it from project root and on.

Answer (score 1):

as you see this is your error:
Target class [RequestManager/Http/Controllers\RequestManager\Http\Controllers\RequestController] does not exist.
in your module you have clean your name space.
pay attention to error, it says you gives me twice name space a

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved when i changed this piece of code ( in my module service provider) :

From :

```
 Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(__DIR__ . './routes/api.php');
```

to :

```
 Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->group(__DIR__ . './routes/api.php');
```